# How to add a label to all emails forwarded to Gmail from another address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I use two email addresses: `me@gmail.com` and `me@other.com`. I automatically forward all emails received to `me@other.com` to `me@gmail.com`. Now I need to set up a filter in my Gmail box so that every email forwarded from `me@other.com` to `me@gmail.com` is marked by a certain label. But I don't know how to filter my incoming emails for the forwarded ones. I tried to filter for emails where the header 'to' contains `me@other.com`. The problem is that this does not filter emails sent to me in a (blinded) copy. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067566?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

> **Label emails automatically**
>   You can label emails as you get them based on specific criteria, like who sent the email or keywords in the email.
>
> 1. On your computer, open [Inbox](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Finbox.google.com%2F&followup=https%3A%2F%2Finbox.google.com%2F&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin).
> 2. On the left, next to the label you want, click **Settings** (gear icon).
> 3. Under "Automatically add messages," click **Add**.
> 4. In the "From" field, click the Down arrow Down Arrow.
> 5. Choose an option.
> 6. Enter a name, email address, or keyword. Emails that would be labeled are shown below.
> 7. To include more criteria, click **And** and repeat steps 5 and 6.
> 8. When you’re finished adding criteria, click **Save**.

Answer (score 0):

besides using a filter to process incoming emails you can use check email from other accounts to pull the email from the other account.

This is done via settings/accounts and import and look for the section called "check email from other accounts"

You can add a label to all the incoming mail, you can also archive all the incoming mail so it skips the inbox. You can decide if you want to delete the mail from the other account as it is pulled.  You will also have to enter the username and password.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is using gmail filter:

- Go to [Gmail Setting/ Filters](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters)
- Click **Create a new filter**
- Fill your other email address in **To**: `To: me@other.com`
- Click **Create filter**
- Tick the checkbox **Apply the label: (label_dropdownlist)** then chose the label you want
- Click **Create filter**
- Done.